# Check the elements of the lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
a = ["000000001111111110101010","111111110000111111000011"]
```

what I need to do is check my `list(a)`,

```
for item in a:
    for elements in range(len(a[item])):
       if "0" in a or "1" in a:
```

random change one elements in `a[item]`(0 change to 1 or 1 change to 0) just one element,how can I do this

in my question if all elements changed should be:

```
a = ["111111110000000001010101","000000001111000000111100"]
```

if just one elements changed should be:

```
a =["000000001111101110101010","111111110000111111001011"]
```

just random pick 0 or 1 to change to 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

The source code below works for me:

```
a = ['000000001111111110101010',"111111110000111111000011"]
print(a)

ret = []
for item in a:
    r = ''
    for i in item:
        b = int(i, base=2)
        c = str(int(not b))
        r = r + c

    ret.append(r)

print(ret)
```

And the output is:

```
['000000001111111110101010', '111111110000111111000011']
['111111110000000001010101', '000000001111000000111100']
```

Comment: how about  iff just one elements changed should be:

a =["000000001111101110101010","111111110000111111001011"]
just random pick 0 or 1 to change to 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

Here are both, flipping all digits and flipping one random digit:

```
import random

def flip_all(s):
    s = list(s)
    return ''.join([str(1 - int(c)) for c in s])

def flip_one(s):
    s = list(s)
    rand_i = random.randint(0, len(s)-1)
    s[rand_i] = str(1 - int(s[rand_i]))
    return ''.join(s)

a = ["000000001111111110101010","111111110000111111000011"]
print("a:        ", a)
print("flip all: ", [flip_all(word) for word in a])
print("flip one: ", [flip_one(word) for word in a])
```

Output:

```
a:         ['000000001111111110101010', '111111110000111111000011']
flip all:  ['111111110000000001010101', '000000001111000000111100']
flip one:  ['000000001101111110101010', '111111110000111110000011']
```

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/252544) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this :)